# Adding Checkout (recursively) to context menu not working

Tags: clearcase

I'm doing like this ..... but i'm not able succeed...
For the check out recursively option, do the following:

1. Start the clearmenuadmin.exe utility (to do this, click Start > Run, and type clearmenuadmin.exe)
2. In the Object type tab, select the directory object. Choose checked-in as the Object state
3. Click the new button in the Available menu Choices pane, and then enter the following information in the appropriate fields:

   - Menu Text: Checkout (recursively)...
   - Help Text: Check out the selected item recursively...
   - Command Type: Executable/Regentry
   - Command:
     Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ContextMenus\CmdLineExe
   - Initial Directory:
     Arguments: /c cleartool find $file -exec "cmd /c cleartool checkout -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
   - Comment:

When this is done, you can add this new menu entry to the This menu contents pane by pressing the Add button. Position it as desired with the Move up button. After completing this customization, choose Configuration>Apply to apply the changes. Then you can test it in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the so-called [ten best scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html)
But we need to know what kind or effort you get when testing it.

For example, in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=236996):

> my test is unsuccessful. I get the following error message:

```
"Failed to load executable name from registry key 'Softwar\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ContextMenus\CmdLineExe', The system cannot find the file specified.
""
```

Which solves itself with:

> Great news, I modified the Menu Item Properties to:

```
Menu Text: Checkout (recursively)...
Help Text: Check out the selected item recursively...
Command Type: Executable
Command: cmd
Initial Directory:
Arguments: /c cleartool find $file -exec "cmd /c cleartool checkout -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
Comment:
```

> And, now both my Check Out (recursively) and Check In (recursively) Context Menu items work - Thank you!

Comment: You'right , it is one of the ten best scripts.. thanks for your reply and it worked