# How to find element(s) which are not present in the clearcase recursively?

Tags: clearcase

How to find element(s) which are not present in the clearcase recursively , let us say from project root folder i want to know the list of files which are not part of clearcase.
Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to find them through the command line interface, in a DOS session for instance:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (`cleartool ls -r -nxn ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed"`) do @echo "%i"
```

(See the discussion on how to find private files in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369697/command-line-to-delete-all-clearcase-view-private-files/369952#369952))

Then, you can add this command to the ClearCase menu entries from the Windows explorer, follwing the process described in the [ten ben scripts article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html).
See also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006322/adding-checkout-recursively-to-context-menu-not-working/2007089#2007089) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012572/how-to-create-undo-checkout-recursively-in-clearcase-in-context-menu/2012688#2012688) for example of menu entries commands (not related to your question, but mentioning a few tip about the commands)

Answer (score 3):

If it's a snapshot view, then from the project root use:

cleartool ls -view -r

If it's a dynamic view, then from anywhere use:

cleartool lsp

Comment: Yes, but those commands also list checkout files, which may not be of interest here.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Clearcase plugin (with RSA I am sure it does) gives an option "Find Resources to add to source control"..
This will list all files which are not in ClearCase repository..
Hope this helped.. :-)

Comment: Is this the plugin for eclipse? If so, what  i'm looking for is to add it to context menu(window exlplorer --> right click) like as you said "Find Resources to add to source control".

Comment: its a plugin for eclipse. this gives you a new tab for clearcase.in that tab there is "Find Resources to add to source control" option..