# Can checkouts in ClearCase effect the build

Tags: build, clearcase, forge

if a file is checked out in ClearCase; it would use the earlier version and still would build, is this correct? I'm thinking they had a checkout that was to fix a build issue and the build failed because of the checkout

Comment: If you want to stop "them" from making checkouts, you can limit the view's capability to make checkouts by users other than the view owner.

Comment: @BrianCain if this is an UCM view, you can also lock the Stream (`cleartool lock -nuser me`) in order to lock for everybody except one. Even for a base ClearCase view, you can lock a branch if your checkout is configured to create a branch.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, clearcase using the current file, so if file is checked out in a view and you build this view it will take the checked out file

However, note that if you do uncheckout and you are not using cmake, it might miss this change, since the timestamp of the file after the uncheckout operation is older

Answer (score 0):

The config spec of a view usually starts with:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
```

That means that, yes, your view will select the current file, whatever the other selection rules are.

I recommend checking for files in checkout, but also hijacked files (modified locally without having been checked out, for snapshot view, or even [eclipsed files for dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798915/clearcase-can-i-hijack-a-file-in-dynamic-view/7799307#7799307)) before starting a build.

[Check also for any other "private" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099057/how-to-find-elements-which-are-not-present-in-the-clearcase-recursively/2099195#2099195) (not initially present and selected in the view), because they also can influence a build by their presence.